# using DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker' in the modal with many views after

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-dropdown-picker

I create DropDownPicker  in expo app and when open it the items in dropdownmenu can't be selected if it is out of the container view how can fixed as the container view is small part of design
this simple example:

```
<View>
  <View>
    some data here.....
  </View>
  <View style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 10 }}>
    here is the DropDownPicker
  </View>
  <View>
    some data here.....
  </View>
</View>
```